# PHP getting array values by using data keys

Tags: php, arrays

I got this array:

```
   $allImmunities = array(
    'poisonPercent' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
    'earthPercent' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
    'paralyzePercent' => '/images/gems/paralyze.gif',
    'deathPercent' => '/images/gems/death.gif',
    'energyPercent' => '/images/gems/energy.gif',
    'icePercent' => '/images/gems/ice.gif',
    'firePercent' => '/images/gems/fire.gif',
    'physicalPercent' => '/images/gems/physical.gif',
    'holyPercent' => '/images/gems/holly.gif',
    'invisiblePercent' => '/images/gems/invisible.gif'
   );
```

And $data variable, which always return something like this:

```
$data = 'physicalPercent:10, icePercent:10, holyPercent:-10';
```

Now I need to explode(?) the $data with **:** to get array keys values or is there any better way?

I wan't it to work like this:

```
$v = explode(':', $data);
```

And then if `$v[0]` is fe. `physicalPercent` then it'll pick the

> `/images/gems/physical.gif`

And at the same, I need to operate the numeric values after the **:**, so I need that to works like this:

```
if($v[1] > xx and $v[1] < yy)
```

pick the array value that is matching with `$v[0]`.

Sorry for my English, I need help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below, perhaps:

```
foreach(explode(', ', $data) as $prop) {
   list($propName, $propVal) = explode(':', $prop);
   // $propName would be physicalPercent, 
   // $propVal would be 10 for the first iteration, etc

   // now get the image
   $img = $allImmunities[$propName];

   echo $img . '<br/>';
}
```

Full code (with your data):

```
<?php
   $allImmunities = array(
    'poisonPercent' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
    'earthPercent' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
    'paralyzePercent' => '/images/gems/paralyze.gif',
    'deathPercent' => '/images/gems/death.gif',
    'energyPercent' => '/images/gems/energy.gif',
    'icePercent' => '/images/gems/ice.gif',
    'firePercent' => '/images/gems/fire.gif',
    'physicalPercent' => '/images/gems/physical.gif',
    'holyPercent' => '/images/gems/holly.gif',
    'invisiblePercent' => '/images/gems/invisible.gif'
   );

$data = 'physicalPercent:10, icePercent:10, holyPercent:-10';
foreach(explode(', ', $data) as $prop) {
   list($propName, $propVal) = explode(':', $prop);
   // $propName would be physicalPercent,
   // $propVal would be 10 for the first iteration, etc

   // now get the image
   $img = $allImmunities[$propName];

   echo $img ."\n";
}
```

output:

```
$ php game.php
/images/gems/physical.gif
/images/gems/ice.gif
/images/gems/holly.gif
```

Comment: fine, but now, how to pick images?

Comment: keep it mind that it will have to pick multiple images (physicalPercent, icePercent, holyPercent).

Comment: ym, ok but $propName returns : instead of physicalPercent for example.

Comment: It sure works on my end, I tested the full code (with your array and $data), try copy pasting the whole code again?

Comment: edited with the full code, just in case I'm missing something

Comment: what I tried to emphasize, you are still using my old code, please repaste. http://pastebin.com/kNtmnAJE

Comment: glad that helped mate :) take it easy

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and explode data to get the info.

Comment: How can I grep 'physicalPercent' and others into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can first explode into the key/value pairs and then retrieve the values based on them:

```
$data = 'physicalPercent:10, icePercent:10, holyPercent:-10';

foreach(explode(', ', $data) as $item)
{
    list($key, $value) = sscanf($item, '%[a-zA-Z]:%d');

    echo $allImmunities[$key], "\n";
}
```

Output ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/NTxTmO6e)):

```
/images/gems/physical.gif
/images/gems/ice.gif
/images/gems/holly.gif
```